# Dynamically set uri of a react native <Image />

Tags: android, ios, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am trying to build a FlatList which will have an icon on the left (pretty much like any Contacts app) and I'm trying to dynamically load an image based on the name of the element

```
<Image
    style={styles.image}
    source={{uri: `./assets/${this.props.name}.png`}}
/>
```

Which is not allowed by React Native, as stated by their [Image](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image.html) docs.
Are there any workaround?

Answer (score 2):

if your image is in your project (eg assets folder) you can not create dynamically, the most you can do is an array to select, like this:

```
var icons = [ require('image!my-icon-active') ,require('image!my-icon-inactive')];
<Image
    style={styles.image}
    source={icons[1]}
/>
```

but you can save the images in a folder and read from your local storage using 'file://' or 'data://' like you are reading from Web, that can be dinamically link:

```
let uri = 'file://'+this.state.pathToResources+'/'+href;
<Image
          style={{width: 400, height: 400}}
          resizeMode='contain'
          source={{uri}}
        />
```

You can use the lib
https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs
for you ready from local disk of your smartphone, but you need manage the height e width.

For more read https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images.html#uri-data-images

Answer (score 0):

Just create a variable in the state:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      imgUri: ""
    }
}

...

<Image
  style={styles.image}
  source={{uri: this.state.uri}}/>
```

Update the uri by calling `this.setState({imgUri: "foobar"})`